# What are some Abstract Data Types in Haskell and how do they differ from Algebraic Data Types?

Tags: haskell

What are some examples of Abstract Data Types in Haskell and what specifically differentiate them from Algebraic Data Types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Abstract data types do not export their implementation, instead preferring to export functions that can be used to build and consume them. There are many fantastic and oft-used examples in the [`containers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers) package; the `Map` type sprung immediately to mind as a type with a very rich API but for which you are not permitted to see the implementation details. The `Set`, `Seq`, and specialized `IntMap` and `IntSet` types are all also abstract.

All Haskell types are algebraic -- this just means they are all constructed from sums, products, function types, and recursion.

Comment: Do you have any more examples of Abstract data types that I can look into further?

Comment: Are primitive types like `Int` and `Char` really considered algebraic?

Comment: @dfeuer Sure, they're just (large but) finite sums.

Comment: @McLeodx There are lots of abstract types. Can you say what you want to get out of your further looking? With a clear goal in mind, it's easier to suggest next steps.